# full calendar change event color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, ice-cube

i have been trying to change the color of my event with no success.

my git-ripo is https://github.com/mzararagoza/rails-fullcalendar-icecube and there is a sample of the site.

i am loading my event on with json that looks like 
http://rails-fullcalendar-icecube.herokuapp.com/event_instances.json

> {
>
> ```
>     "_routes": null,
>     "title": "ddd",
>     "color": "#b319ab",
>     "url": "/events/6",
>     "start": "2013-06-12T00:00:00-05:00",
>     "end": "2013-06-12T23:59:59-05:00",
>     "allDay": true,
>     "event_id": 6
>
> }
> ```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: the problem i was having was in the CSS sheet that i was loading

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning a **classname** to it and define that class inside a CSS block of code, just like this one:

```
<style>    
.myCalendarEvent{
            color:#000;
            background-color:#FFF;
            border-color:#669999;   
            width: 100%;                
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the color for all events, the recommanded way is to use fullCalendar's API:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventColor: '#yourcolor'
});
```

To change a specific event's color knowing it's id:

```
event = $('#full-calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', event_id)
event.color = '#yourcolor'
$('#full-calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event)
```